# NGINX: How to redirect the domain with parameters in the url?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have been trying to redirect a URL to another domain using URL rewriting.
Below is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
            listen       8070;
            server_name  www.example.com;
            rewrite ^/v1/([0-9]+).html http://www.example.com/v1?exid=$1;


            location ~ /v1/([0-9]+) {
                return 301 http://dev.example1.com/v1?exid==$1;
            }
        }
}
```

I have been trying for a long time but I am still not able to find a proper solution.

NOTE: I didn't get any errors if I try the above but the expected redirecting does not occur.
I want this Url to be redirected 
http://example.com/v1/68740.html ---to---> http://dev.example1.com/v1?exid=68740.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to at least give information regarding what is happening (and/or the errors you're getting, in case), if that differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: Hi, @gf I have updated my question with a Note...could u please refer it.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your configuration file. The `rewrite` is missing `https://` from the target URL, and the `return` statement has `==`. The `#featured` is not passed to `nginx`, are you sure that the link is not handled internally by the browser?

Comment: What is your complete nginx configuration? Edit it into the question.

Comment: Hi, Kilkanen could you please see above edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 8070;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite_log on;

  location ~^/v1/([\d]+)\.html$ {
    return 301 http://dev.example1.com/v1?exid=$1;
  }
}
```

If you want to debug configuration of ngx_http_rewrite_module, set rewrite_log directive on.
For details on rewrite_log :

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log

You had better check access_log finally your nginx returned (redirected) URL finally.

Comment: Hi..minish.Thanks... could u please explain the above configuration file..if u don't mind

Comment: `rewrite_log on;` writes detailed ngx_http_rewrite_module log to error log. You can turn off if not need.
caret( `^` ) stands for begining of string, dollar sign( `$` ) stands for end of string.
`\d` is the meta character for `[0-9]` . You can write `\d` or `[0-9]` .
The caputured expression  `(\d+)` is put the positional variable `$1` .

Comment: Hi ...Minish ..Thank you...I have followed what you have said..but still, If I hit this URL: http://example.com/v1/68740.html, it could not redirect to http://dev.example1.com/v1?exid=68740.  (it remains the same page)
Also, I didn't get any errors in error log file and it shows signal process started

Comment: Hi, Ramyachinna.
I'm sorry and I corrected the above config, ` \d ` to ` [\d] ` .

And checked with curl command:
` curl -v -H 'Host: www.example.com' 'http://localhost:8070/v1/000.html' `

The nginx server response was:

`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 10 May 2017 13:50:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://dev.example1.com/v1?exid=000
`

Comment: Hi, Minish...great answers thank you so much it works for me. But can't able to vote because of my less reputations

Comment: I'm simply glad to help for you!